Open URL on Tap of AppIntent Button Action Of widget?
open a url on tap of appointment button action, for below code
I had tried this
struct RepeatOrderIntent: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Seasia Intent"
    init(){}
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        OrderManger.shared.openInstagram()
        //WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
        return .result()
    }
}

func openInstagram() {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://www.instagram.com/") {
        openURL(url)
    }
}

struct OpenURLIntent {
    var url: String
    @Environment(\.openURL) private var openURL
    func execute() {
        guard let url = URL(string: self.url) else { return }
        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
        openURL(url)
    }
}

But link won't open, please guide me.

Please include the code of openInstagram() function

openURL(:) function is also missing here. Please show us what you are trying to do for us to be able to help.
